# How I should deal with different response using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm using `ember-data`, but when use `find` to search place, and get a list of places for user. My payload may contain a list of places, how I should normalize this response. `store.find` don't allowed a array. How I deal with this list?

Follow a error which I get cause this.

```
Cannot read property 'getRecord' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRecord' of undefined
```

Comment: Use `store.findAll('place')` and take a look at https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/models/finding-records.

Comment: OK, but when I use findAll i can't search for a specific user.

Comment: That's what `queryRecord` is for.

Answer (score 2):

`.find('place', id)` is to get a *single* record from its *id*!
You *should* use `.query('place', { filter: { user: user } })` to *search* records based on a filter and `.findAll('place')` to get *all* records from a given type.

You probably should use `.query` or use a `hasMany` *relationship* on a `user` model!